# zsh: get status of last prompted command? (get value of `%?` in a function)

Tags: zsh

I want to get the status of the command executed by the last prompt, what in prompt expansion would be `%?`, but I want to get it inside a function.  (Why?  I like the idea of `%?` in the prompt, but thought it would be nice to dress it up a bit by rendering it as something other than just a number: “EX_USAGE” instead of “64” or “SIGILL” instead of “132”.  That means passing the value of `%?` to a function to generate the text that appears in the prompt.)

The obvious answer is `print -P %?`, but it doesn’t work: it returns the same thing as `$?`, which is the status of the last command executed anywhere, including inside command substitution for the prompt.  Not surprisingly, the `%` expansion flag has the same problem.  (I’m not sure if this is a bug or if it’s working as designed.)  I could use a `precmd` function to save `$?` in a global, but *only* if I could guarantee that it was called before anything else, and that’s not a promise I’m comfortable making.

Any suggestions?  zsh clearly has the value I want, since it uses it in prompt percent expansion, but how do I get at it?  It’s fine if the solution requires being in a function called by prompt substitution, since that’s what I’m doing already, but bonus points if it works elsewhere.  If it makes a difference, I’m using zsh 5.3.